# Specify 'using static' only for debug build in blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

In my blazor app, I use `using static` to simplify console logging:

`_Layout.razor`:

```cs
@using static System.Console
```

`SomeComponent.razor`:

```cs
WriteLine("foo");       // instead of Console.WriteLine("foo");
```

I want that only in DEBUG builds, but I cannot use `#if DEBUG` in a `_Layout.razor` file.

Is there some way to include it only for DEBUG, or perhaps a way to include a `_LayoutDebug.razor` file only for DEBUG (in the project's `.csproj`)?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a logger method and inside that method, you can use preprocessor directive. I mean this;

```cs
public void Log(string message)
{
#if DEBUG
      Console.WriteLine(message);
#endif
}
```

Comment: That is an option which I imagine could be useful in various use cases - thanks for posting it... upvoted! Personally however, I want to exclude the static imports completely, rather than just disable their behaviour.